# Can I push my code to the same GitHub repository if I change the project name locally on my computer?

Tags: android, flutter, github, github-actions

I am working on a project that's been cloned from the GitHub repository. Before, I kept working on it with the demo/sample **name** locally and on the GitHub repository as well. But now as I have completed it, I had to change its name.

Now the question is can I still push my code from my local device with **different project name** to the same old repository that I have been working on but with different name?

Comment: change the repo name same as newProjectName and try again, then try with adding origin

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can push with locally another branch. if you didn't have a git folder in your project then simply put the command

```
git init
```

else

Create New Branch

```
git checkout -b dev
```

Add Remote of your Existing Branch

```
git remote add origin <https://github.com/your git repo link>
```

And then finally push on GitHub

```
git push -u origin dev
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the time to read up on [markdown formatting in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your answer accordingly. Right now it is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. They're connected using the link you provided before when you commanded `git remote add origin 'your link'`. You can also change Github app name from settings.